# Dynamically load data in highcharts ng

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, highcharts-ng

I am working on highcharts ng for my angular project but the data is not getting filled.
I think there might be an issue related to the loading of the DOM and the called function.

my HTML part :

```html
<div style="width: 49%; float:right;"><highchart id="chart12" config="highchartsNG"></highchart></div>
```

Module part :

```js
myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['LocalStorageModule', 'ui.bootstrap', 'highcharts-ng', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'angular-loading-bar', 'hc.marked', 'ngToast', 'angularMoment', 'slick', 'app-templates']);
```

controller part:

```js
myApp.controller('ReportController', ['$scope', 'CompanyService', function ($scope, CompanyService) {
    (function () {
        loadReport();
    })();

    function loadReport() {
      CompanyService.getReportData().then(function (data) {
        if (data.status === 200){
            $scope.dates = data.data.date;
            $scope.counts = data.data.count;

            $scope.fetchedData = {
              data: data.data.count
            };
            //
            // console.log("dates ==> ", $scope.dates);          // ["2017-03-14", "2017-03-19"]
            // console.log("counts ==> ", $scope.counts);   // {data: [22, 15]}

        }
      }, function (error) {

      });
    };

    $scope.dates = ['2017-03-19', '2017-03-18', '2017-03-17', '2017-03-16', '2017-03-15', '2017-03-14', '2017-03-13'];
    $scope.counts = [2,10,20, 25, 5, 15, 8];

  $scope.$watchGroup(['counts', 'dates'], function(newValues, oldValues) {

    // newValues[0] --> $scope.line
    // newValues[1] --> $scope.bar

    if(newValues !== oldValues) {
      $scope.highchartsNG = {
          chart: {
              type: 'column'
          },
          title: {
              text: 'Stacked column chart'
          },
          xAxis: {
              categories: $scope.dates
          },
          yAxis: {
              min: 0,
              title: {
                  text: 'Total count'
              },
              stackLabels: {
                  enabled: true,
                  style: {
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                  }
              }
          },
          legend: {
              align: 'right',
              x: -70,
              verticalAlign: 'top',
              y: 20,
              floating: true,
              backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
              borderColor: '#CCC',
              borderWidth: 1,
              shadow: false
          },
          tooltip: {
              formatter: function() {
                  return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                      this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                      'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
              }
          },
          plotOptions: {
              column: {
                  stacking: 'normal',
                  dataLabels: {
                      enabled: true,
                      color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                      style: {
                          textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                      }
                  }
              }
          },
          series: [{
            data: $scope.counts
          }]
      };
    }
  });

}]);
```

I have [referred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848656/highcharts-ng-ajax-data-load) and tried to implement it, but there are console errors

TypeError: Cannot set property 'getChartObj' of undefined
    at HighChartNGController.$onInit

I think a function should be invoked after the DOM loads, which is actually taken care by `$watchGroup`. But I am not able to figure out how.
Any suggestions will be of real help.

Comment: Why are you using watch  , assign value to  $scope.highchartsNG in controller from  loadReport directly. Also you need to define  $scope.highchartsNG config in advance then change assign data only.

Comment: I tried assigning the values directly, but series data is not getting added, so I then went on to read the mentioned article, to use watch for looking onto the data changes. which also couldn't fix this.

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code**

```
   myApp.controller('ReportController', ['$scope', 'CompanyService', function ($scope, CompanyService) {
  (function () {
    loadReport();


      })();

      $scope.highchartsNG = {
        chart: {
          type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
          min: 0,
          title: {
            text: 'Total count'
          },
          stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
          }
        },
        legend: {
          align: 'right',
          x: -70,
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          y: 20,
          floating: true,
          backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
          borderColor: '#CCC',
          borderWidth: 1,
          shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function() {
            return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
            this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
            'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
          }
        },
        plotOptions: {
          column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
              style: {
                textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
              }
            }
          }
        },
        series: [{
          data: []
        }]
      };

      function loadReport() {
        CompanyService.getReportData().then(function (data) {
          if (data.status === 200){
            $scope.dates = data.data.date;
            $scope.counts = data.data.count;

            $scope.fetchedData = {
              data: data.data.count
            };
                //
                // console.log("dates ==> ", $scope.dates);          // ["2017-03-14", "2017-03-19"]
                // console.log("counts ==> ", $scope.counts);   // {data: [22, 15]}

              }
            }, function (error) {

            });
      };

      $scope.dates = ['2017-03-19', '2017-03-18', '2017-03-17', '2017-03-16', '2017-03-15', '2017-03-14', '2017-03-13'];
      $scope.counts = [2,10,20, 25, 5, 15, 8];

          //Assign old value
          $scope.highchartsNG.series[0].data=$scope.counts;
          $scope.highchartsNG.xAxis.categories=$scope.dates;  



      $scope.$watchGroup(['counts', 'dates'], function(newValues, oldValues) {

        // newValues[0] --> $scope.line
        // newValues[1] --> $scope.bar

        if(newValues !== oldValues) {

          //Assign value only
          $scope.highchartsNG.series[0].data=$scope.counts;
          $scope.highchartsNG.xAxis.categories=$scope.dates;     

        }
      });

    }]);
```

2nd Version

```
myApp.controller('ReportController', ['$scope', 'CompanyService', function ($scope, CompanyService) {


  $scope.highchartsNG = {
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: []
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Total count'
      },
      stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      align: 'right',
      x: -70,
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 20,
      floating: true,
      backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
      borderColor: '#CCC',
      borderWidth: 1,
      shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
        this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
        'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
          style: {
            textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: []
    }]
  };


  $scope.dates = ['2017-03-19', '2017-03-18', '2017-03-17', '2017-03-16', '2017-03-15', '2017-03-14', '2017-03-13'];
  $scope.counts = [2,10,20, 25, 5, 15, 8];




    //Assign old value
    $scope.highchartsNG.series[0].data=$scope.counts;
    $scope.highchartsNG.xAxis.categories=$scope.dates;  

    CompanyService.getReportData().then(function (data) {
      if (data.status === 200){
        $scope.dates = data.data.date;
        $scope.counts = data.data.count;

        $scope.fetchedData = {
          data: data.data.count
        };

        $scope.highchartsNG.series[0].data=$scope.counts;
        $scope.highchartsNG.xAxis.categories=$scope.dates;    

                //
                // console.log("dates ==> ", $scope.dates);          // ["2017-03-14", "2017-03-19"]
                // console.log("counts ==> ", $scope.counts);   // {data: [22, 15]}

              }
            }, function (error) {

            });



          /*$scope.$watchGroup(['counts', 'dates'], function(newValues, oldValues) {



            if(newValues !== oldValues) {

             //Assign value only
             $scope.highchartsNG.series[0].data=$scope.counts;
             $scope.highchartsNG.xAxis.categories=$scope.dates;     

           }
         });*/

       }]);
```

Comment: The solution is not showing any console error, but its not populating the graph either.

Comment: make sure watchGroup group working there. you are getting in if condition.

Comment: Yes, its working and I am getting into the if condition pretty well. But the chart is not redrawing.

Comment: Try changing 
if(newValues !== oldValues) {

          //Assign value only
          $scope.highchartsNG.series[0].data=$scope.counts;
          $scope.highchartsNG.xAxis.categories=$scope.dates;     
        $scope.$digest();


        }

Comment: I have tried using the digest and apply utils earlier, but these throws an error.
Even the values of series and categories are changing, but not reflecting on the graph.
the data of newValues is was updated from the loadReport function too.

Issues with the redraw functionality of highcharts-ng

Comment: check using 2nd version